# Postfix relay with STARTTLS - TLS is required, but was not offered by host

Tags: postfix

i need send email through an exetrnal SMTP, is use STARTTLS, my postconf -n is:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mynetworks = 0.0.0.0/0
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
relayhost = xx.xx.xx.xx:2525
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_policy_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/tls_policy
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd

```
xx.xx.xx.xx:2525   user:password
```

/etc/postfix/tls_policy

```
xx.xx.xx.xx:2525 encrypt
```

I have this error:

```
Jul  6 17:49:11 ip-10-1-4-140 postfix/smtp[25156]: 95F826276D: to=<foo@bar.com>, relay=xx.xx.xx.xx[xx.xx.xx.xx]:2525, delay=0.43, delays=0.23/0.01/0.19/0, dsn=4.7.4, status=deferred (TLS is required, but was not offered by host xx.xx.xx.xx[xx.xx.xx.xx])
```

Any idea?

Comment: Are you behind a Cisco firewall?  I found the problem to be my Cisco ios firewall was inspecting and filtering EHLO commands, replacing STARTTLS with 250-XXXXXXX.  I had to remove the Cisco esmtp inspection filter.

Answer (score 2):

This is something that could happen when you have `smtp_use_tls = yes`.

> [`smtp_use_tls`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_use_tls) (default: `no`)
>
> Opportunistic mode: use TLS when a remote SMTP server announces
>   STARTTLS support, otherwise send the mail in the clear. Beware: some
>   SMTP servers offer STARTTLS even if it is not configured. With Postfix
>   < 2.3, if the TLS handshake fails, and no other server is available,
>   delivery is deferred and mail stays in the queue. If this is a concern
>   for you, use the [smtp_tls_per_site](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_tls_per_site) feature instead.

Comment: I have set `smtp_use_tls` to `no` but i get same error

Comment: You still have `xx.xx.xx.xx:2525 encrypt` in `smtp_tls_policy_maps`. Obviously, it doesn't really offer TLS.

Comment: Old comments/answer, but ended up here. Yes, as @EsaJokinen states: If you have "encrypt" set on policy maps you are enforcing TLS throughout the client exchange (local or remote). If you remove 'encrypt' from that directive, it will allow opportunistic TLS mode via `smtp_tls_security_level=may` directive. I've also found that you can also leave the `smtp_use_tls=yes` if you set 'may' for security level.

Answer (score 1):

No need to do any changes in postfix. 
Just check your router/firewall is allowing mail services.
You can test it by following below command.

***telnet smtp.gmail.com 587*** <-- enter

enter your Gmail username.

***EHLO foo@gmail.com*** <-- enter,

after this you should see output like below.

250-smtp.gmail.com

250-8BITMIME

250-SIZE 10485760

***250-STARTTLS***

250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN

250 Ok

421 Timeout waiting fothe r data from client.

If you are not finding ***STARTTLA*** then your router/firewall is blocking.
Unblock the 25,587 and 465 it will work fine.

I hope, this will solve your issue.

Comment: To get this to work I had to use my server's domain name, not my gmail address. Aka `EHLO mydomain.com`. (Not myemail@mydomain.com, but just my domain name). Anyway it did confirm I'm using TLS; however, I'm still not able to force Gmail to use TLS.